# How can you rename a label on a button using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I'm trying to work out a way of replacing a button label 'Add to bag' to 'Add to basket' using JQuery as I don't have access to the HTML on the page.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="element add_to_bag_button" >
        <button type="submit" class="submit button btn btn_primary btn_large">Add to bag</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried various versions of this JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main button.submit button btn btn_primary btn_large').replaceWith('Add to basket');
});
```

Clearly it's wrong but I don't quite know how to target the content within the  tag.

JFiddle is here: [http://jsfiddle.net/0wwhrfry/]

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1) you need to use correct selector to target button

2)Use `.text()` to set the text:

```
$('#main .btn_large').text('Add to basket');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/msda0aLq/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can change the selectors as per requirement. The thing here you need is jQuery code.
Kindly find below snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').html('Add to basket');
});
```

If you have parent ID (like here) you have #main so can simply change the selector as below:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#main button').html('Add to basket');
 });
```

OR

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#main button.submit').html('Add to basket');
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0wwhrfry/2/)

Hope this will fix your query.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `.text()`

```
$('button.submit').text('Add to basket');
```

**Edit**: Also, as Milind points out, you don't need such a huge selector.

In fact, (I know you're probably using it anyway), but you don't need jQuery for something so simple:

```
var button = document.querySelector(".button.submit");
button.textContent = "New value"
```